# method that Searches over specific columns in a table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I need to create a method to search over a specific table `tournaments`, the method should search through the following columns :
- name
- address
- starts_on
- ends_on
- city
- postcode

I am unsure how to do that, so far I have written a class method in my tournament model that looks like that :

```
 def self.search(term)
    Tournament.where('name ILIKE ? OR starts_on ILIKE ? OR ends_on ILIKE ?' , "%#{term}%")
  end
```

How can I and what is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a parameter like this:

```
def self.search(term)
    Tournament.where('name ILIKE :theString OR starts_on ILIKE :theString OR ends_on ILIKE :theString' ,theString: "%#{term}%")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Are your search fields discrete fields?

you could chain 'where' methods based on the presence of each search term.

```
def self.search(name, starts_on, ends_on, city, postcode)  
  terms = {name: name, 
           starts_on: starts_on, 
           ends_on: ends_on, 
           city: city, 
           post_code: postcode }
  @tournaments = Tournament.all
  terms.each do |term, value|
     @tournaments = @tournaments.where("#{term.to_s} ILIKE ?", value) if value
  end
  @tournaments
end
```